# XNA Diagonal Movement Key Release

Tags: c#, xna, game-physics

Ok, so say you're playing a top down game. You press `W` and `D` to go in the up-right direction. Now you just want to go right, so you release the `W` key. One would expect you to then change directions and head right, but instead, you continue up-right. What can I do to solve this problem?
Here is my code:

```
        if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) || kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) || kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) || kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
                velocity.Y = -movespeed;
            else if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                velocity.X = -movespeed;
            else if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                velocity.Y = movespeed;
            else if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                velocity.X = movespeed;
            else if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) && kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                velocity.X = movespeed;
                velocity.Y = -movespeed;
            }
            else if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) && kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                velocity.X = -movespeed;
                velocity.Y = -movespeed;
            }
            else if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) && kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                velocity.X = movespeed;
                velocity.Y = movespeed;
            }
            else if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) && kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                velocity.X = -movespeed;
                velocity.Y = movespeed;
            }
        }
        else
            velocity *= .9f;

        position += velocity;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the answer myself after a few hours of struggle.

Simply setting the velocity to zero before the checks worked:
EDIT: multiplying it by .89 actually made for much smoother movement.

```
        if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) || kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) || kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) || kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            velocity *= .89f
            if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
                velocity.Y = -movespeed;
            if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                velocity.X = -movespeed;
            if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                velocity.Y = movespeed;
            if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                velocity.X = movespeed;
        }
        else
            velocity *= .9f;
```

Comment: did you consider that diagonal speed is faster than moving up/down/left/right? one solution is to normalize velocity and then multiply by speed. other is to divide speed by `sqrt(2)` if movement is diagonal.

Comment: No, I didn't. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The diagonal speed will be `speed magnitude * sqrt(2)`.